# Why does a Baal Tokeiah wear a new garment on the second day of Rosh Hashanah

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

I remember reading that a Baal Tokeiah is supposed to wear a new garment on the second day of Rosh Hashanah and it may have something to do with a Shechiyanu Bracha that he makes? Can someone please explain above ?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 600:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.600.3?lang=bi) records differing practices regarding reciting *shehecheyanu* on *shofar* on the second day of Rosh HaShanah (when not on Sunday).

Magen Avraham ad loc. recommends that those who do recite *shehecheyanu* wear a new garment (presumably as a way of resolving the doubt; even if the *shofar* doesn’t require *shehecheyanu*, the new garment does).